# How to split the csv file based on the condition of increasing decreasing value?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have csv file which i read as dataframe. I have one column = river_km which is variate between 1100 and 1247 value. I want to split this file according to behaviour of this value(each file should have value between 1100 and 1247 or 1247-1100). The problem is that this value not always go to the pick=1247 sometimes it can go to the 1100 and then decrease. I try to use monotonic function but it doesn't split my data correctly. What can I use in this case for splitting the files?

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter=';')
print(df.river_km)
df = df[:66500]

iter_num = 50
previous_status = 0
previous_traj = 0
for row in range(0,len(df),iter_num):

L = df.river_km[row:row+iter_num]
##test_list = df.river_km[132970:132985]
#print(test_list)
#
#time = df.datetime[172749:172778]
#print(time)


def strictly_increasing(L):
    return all(x<y for x, y in zip(L, L[1:]))

def strictly_decreasing(L):
    return all(x>y for x, y in zip(L, L[1:]))

def non_increasing(L):
    return all(x>=y for x, y in zip(L, L[1:]))

def non_decreasing(L):
    return all(x<=y for x, y in zip(L, L[1:]))

def monotonic(L):
    return non_increasing(L) or non_decreasing(L)


increase = strictly_increasing(L)
decrease = strictly_decreasing(L)
non_increase = non_increasing(L)
non_decrease = non_decreasing(L)
monotonic = monotonic(L)


"""incresing = 1
decreasing = 2
nothing = 3"""


if increase == True and decrease == False and non_increase == False and non_decrease == True and monotonic == True:
    current_status = 1

elif increase == False and decrease == True and non_increase == True and non_decrease == False and monotonic == True:
    current_status = 2

else:     
    current_status = 3

if current_status == 3:
   L.loc['Route'] = previous_traj

elif current_status != previous_status:
    previous_traj = previous_traj + 1
    L.loc['Route'] = previous_traj
    previous_status = current_status
else:
    L.loc['Route'] = previous_traj
```

Comment: Welcome to stack. It's not clear what you want to achieve. It's always better to put a data example as input and  what you was as output incase if possible. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `pd.cut` to create bins of range then tag a specific column with an appropriate name for a given value of your `river_km` column? Then use these `tags` as parameter for `isin()` then filter your dataframe. Each tag value will then be an individual dataframe.